# Java Library for (Furthest Point) Voronoi Diagram

Tags: java, computational-geometry, voronoi

I've been searching on Google for hours but I can't find a Java library to calculate (Furthest Point) Voronoi Diagrams.

There are some applets out there that happily draw a Voronoi diagram but I haven't seen one that has it's source code available.

The question that I'm trying to answer is 'what are the defining points for this Voronoi vertex', 'what is the point closest to this Voronoi vertex', and 'what is the point furthest away from this Voronoi vertex'.

I'll also accept a pointer to a good explanation on how to write my own (Furthest Point) Voronoi Diagram algorithm. Note that I'm not really concerned with efficiency, I'm just trying to prove that using these two Voronoi diagrams can solve my problem.

Note that I need both FPVDs and VDs :)

*azraelAT helped me find a library for normal Voronoi diagrams but I have still found no library that can compute Farthest Point Voronoi Diagrams!*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Furthest-point Voronoi diagram in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123538/furthest-point-voronoi-diagram-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

For a pointer to an algorithm you can see at:

SKYUM, Sven. [A simple algorithm for computing the smallest enclosing circle](http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/daimipb/article/viewFile/6704/5821). *Information Processing Letters*, 1991, 37.3: 121-125.

The abstract claims

> ... algorithm for computing ... farthest-point Voronoi diagram of a
>   pointset

but the explanation (in Section 3) specifies a **convex** pointset. I do not know the relationship between the FPVD of a set of points S and the FPVD of, for example, the convex hull of S.

EDIT:

Shamos in his Ph.D. dissertation wrote (p.201):

> By Theorem 6.31, this diagram [the FPVD] is determined only by points on the
>   convex hull and these are all exposed, so there are no bounded
>   regions.

Michael Ian Shamos. 1978. *[Computational Geometry](http://euro.ecom.cmu.edu/people/faculty/mshamos/1978ShamosThesis.pdf)*. Ph.D. Dissertation. Yale University, New Haven, CT, USA. AAI7819047.

I read you are looking for a java solution but [here](http://gitorious.org/qhull) you can find a C solution explained at [qvoronoi Qu -- furthest-site Voronoi diagram](http://www.qhull.org/html/qvoron_f.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [Tektosyne](https://github.com/kynosarges/tektosyne) library.

It can generate Voronoi diagrams and Delaunay triangulations, with conversion to DCEL subdivisions and has support for graph algorithms like A* pathfinding, path coverage, flood fill, line of sigh.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many free libraries out there wich create Voronoi diagrams vrom various sorts of input data.

Check out simplevoronoi for example:http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplevoronoi/

Comment: I've been playing with that one for about an hour now, it seems to work fine however the data needs a lot of massaging (since it only outputs edges). One question though, it doesn't calculate the Furthest Point Voronoi Diagram, but is that just repeating the algorithm for n-1 times?