# Furthest-point Voronoi diagram in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, computational-geometry, voronoi

I'm looking for a naive algorithm to find the furthest point Voronoi diagram. Input sizes are not going to be big enough where I need something complex and as there are no Java libraries that I can find.

I was hoping someone could describe a simple algorithm that shouldn't be too hard to compute?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an algorithm pseduocode for farthest-point Voronoi diagram [here](http://www.nirarebakun.com/voro/efpvoro.html). The Java code written by the same person is [here](http://www.nirarebakun.com/voro/fpvoro.java).

Comment: Thanks, Managed to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of a late addition, but you might want to take a look at the [Tektosyne](https://github.com/kynosarges/tektosyne) library.

It can generate Voronoi diagrams and Delaunay triangulations, with conversion to DCEL subdivisions and has support for graph algorithms like A* pathfinding, path coverage, flood fill, line of sigh.